# VideoView: seekTo without loading (buffering)

Tags: android, android-videoview

```
videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("video stream url"));
videoView.seekTo(1000);
```

I'm using VideoView for wathching video from videostream. And there was a need seek to without loading(buffering) full video. Someone knows tips or triks to do that? Thank you!

Comment: depends on the format of the video.